# Can my iPhone be provisioned on two profiles?

Tags: xcode, appcelerator, provisioning, ios-provisioning

I have someone building an app for me on Appcelerator. I'm building an app on Xcode. My phone is provisioned for my own use, but since they can't send me an Xcode file, can I get my phone provisioned for that use also without losing my own profile?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can add your device for development in two developer accounts. And create two provisioning profiles( dev or adhoc).

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in adding your Device UDID to multiple provisional profiles or developer accounts. You will be able to install the build from these accounts in which your device is added.